# starting google script

Tags: google-apps-script

When I go to http://script.google.com i get a screen that looks like Google script but:

1. There is no sidebar like the one in the tutorial video.
2. I can't type anything in.
3. The document is blank, I don't see an image like the tutorial shows.

#### image from tutorial

[image: tutorial image]

I'm logged in using a Gmail account. This is my first time using this program so I'm quite confused.

Comment: can you post an image somewhere of what you do see?

Comment: unfortunately i don't know how to do that. but it looks regular except everything under where the buttons (undo, redo, save, deploy as web app, current project's triggers, run, debug, and select function) is blank and i cannot type anything in

Comment: is there any option that would be like "edit script" that i may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to drive, then creating spreadsheet, then go to tools, then select script editor. Best of luck, know that (as far as I know) its only javascript.

Also check out: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: i tried going to internet explorer instead of using google chrome and it worked fine. for some reason it was google chrome that was causing it to come up wrong

Comment: You might like to see if it works in an incognito instance in Chrome, in which case it might be a browser extension that is fouling it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to create a GAS project that is not part of a spreadsheet, you will need to add the Script component to your drive to edit the script. You add it via the 'Create' button then 'Connect More Apps' and find the 'Google Apps Script' app in the Chrome store.

If you domain has the Chrome store disabled then this URL takes you directly to creating a new script:
https://script.google.com (https being the key - http directs you to a GAS info page)

To edit scripts without the Script applet, you can get the share-url and use it as a direct link to the edit view of the script.